# What are specific tools I can use to create a 2D Array that is a maze?

Tags: java

I am given an assignment to create an Maze with a 2D array.
I am told I need to implement the Union-Find algorithm to generate the mazes of arbitrary size. Then I need to break every wall intill every cell is reachable from every cell.

```
int[][] matrix = new int[N][M];
```

The cells are the individual array indexes, but what are the walls? I was thinking of making my own data type of maze with constructors for the 4 directions such as

```
Maze maze = new Maze() //fill in constructor as needed
```

The array values are from 0-9, what can I use to represent the walls?

Comment: I think you'd be better off making a `MazeCell`[][] maze = new ...` where MazeCell has attributes for North, South, East, West walls, etc

Comment: what data type do you recommend I use then if i did that for the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Use ASCII art. You can use '|' for vertical walls and '-' for horizontal walls. It's basic, but once you can ensure that this works, you can move on to graphics that are more pleasing to the eye. It's important to first make sure it's functional before you make it pretty.

Comment: - -
 | | |
  - -,         I am having a hard time getting them aligned. Was this what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes. If the answer I provided helps, please upvote it! :) How do you align them in code?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create two Classes, one for your whole Maze and one for a Cell which represents a Coordinate in your Maze. If the Coordinate is actually a wall, use a simple bool value. For your algorithm maybe have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Maybe this snippet gets you started:

```
public class Maze {
        private int X_dim, Y_dim; // the dimension of your maze
        private Cell[][] cells; // 2d array of Cells

        public Maze(int X_dim, int Y_dim) {
            this.X_dim = X_dim;
            this.Y_dim = Y_dim;
        }
    }

    public class Cell {
        private Point coordinate;
        boolean visited = false;
        // if true, this Cell represents a wall
        boolean wall = true;

        Cell(Point coordinate, boolean isWall) {
            this.coordinate = coordinate;
            this.wall = isWall;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't a cell have 4 walls? If its in the 2D array, then a cell constructor could be cell(bool Northwall,bool Southwall,bool Eastwall, Bool Westwall)

Comment: It depends what your approach is. You can decide a Wall has no dimension and a Cell can only be surrounded by 4 Walls - or a Cell can actually be a Wall with the dimension of a Cell, think of it like a field of pixels (this maze would be actually 3 times smaller compared to approach one ). Second approach is definitely easier, because if you don't have to care about the neighbour cells, e.g. if 'cell_1.leftWall = true'  you also need to take care of the cell left of cell_1 : 'cell_left.rightWall = true'

Comment: I am going to go with your approach, It is definitely easier to work with in the long term for the logic